# route for area in global.asax file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application I have Admin area and have default controllers outside area. I want to define route in global.asax file so that both default and admin.
like if user type: {http://localhost/} -> open default route
if user type: {http://localhost/Admin/} -> open admin route

If someone has idea to handle this then please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Admin area registration file. Such as:

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Then call this from your Global.asax

```
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. I typed {http://localhost/Admin/} but it did not work

Comment: Make sure your AdminController is in the namespace: Application.Admin.Controllers